# Python Transpose data and change to 0,1's

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have some data in the following format, thousands of rows.

I want to transpose the data and also change the format to 1 and 0's

```
Name Codes
Dave DSFFS
Dave SDFDF
stu  SDFDS
stu  DSGDSG
```

I want to retain the Name column in row format, but have the codes column go into Column format instead and have 1 and 0's

Comment: Please give an example of your desired output.

Comment: It's hard to put formatting in stackoverflow. I want the codes like DSFFS, SDFDF etc to be the column headers. a 1 if Dave has that code, a zero if he does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) should help here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Dave','Dave','stu','stu'],
                   'Codes': ['DSFFS','SDFDF','SDFDS','DSGDSG']})
print(df)
    Codes  Name
0   DSFFS  Dave
1   SDFDF  Dave
2   SDFDS   stu
3  DSGDSG   stu

print(pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Codes']))
   Name  Codes_DSFFS  Codes_DSGDSG  Codes_SDFDF  Codes_SDFDS
0  Dave            1             0            0            0
1  Dave            0             0            1            0
2   stu            0             0            0            1
3   stu            0             1            0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use `df.transpose()` in pandas!

Comment: thanks, but I also need to change to 1,0 at the same time

Comment: Maybe u can replace all the values?